# What does "push ebp" mean in x86 assemby?

Tags: assembly, x86

I disassembled an .exe file and got this as its first line.

```
push ebp
```

- What does it mean?
- Why `ebp`?
- Does it have anything to do with `pop` command? even though I don't see it in the disassembly!

Comment: You don't see corresponding `pop` command in the disassembly, because the [`LEAVE`](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_154.html) instruction is used instead.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`push ebp` just means pushing whatever is in [register](http://www.eecg.toronto.edu/~amza/www.mindsec.com/files/x86regs.html) `ebp` onto the stack. `ebp` stores the stack pointer by convention.

This is generally used to establish a [stack frame](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack), followed by

```
mov     ebp, esp
```

Comment: You may also see the instruction LEAVE at the end of the function, which is equivalent to MOV ESP,EBP followed by POP EBP.  That's why you may not see an explicit pop.

Comment: So, does this mean that all applications start with `push ebp` followed by `mov ebp, esp`?

Comment: Most. All apps that use the ebp register for variable addressing or whatever must restore the calling program's stack frame.

Answer (score 2):

It pushes the value of the EBP register on the stack, and is most commonly used to set up a stackframe. `Pop` retrieves a value from the stack.

Answer (score 2):

The push instruction saves the value of a register onto the stack. The value can later be retrieved using a pop-instruction.

Wikipedia Stack (data structure): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28data_structure%29